# Do multiple flags of the same type accumulate, like votes?

Tags: support, flags

So, I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36571685/what-is-the-best-tool-for-tensor-in-python) question, which is undoubtedly off-topic. There is also a comment stating this fact.

My question is: Should I bother flagging a question like this when it is clear (e.g. from the comments) that someone else has probably already raised the same type of flag?

Is it clogging up a queue somewhere needlessly because flags don't accumulate in the same way as close-votes, (`flag_count = min(flag_count, 1)`), or do additional flags actually help in some way?

Comment: If you can't close vote then flagging is appropriate. Those close votes might be retracted...although it's unlikely. You've done your civic duty and that's never a bad thing. Doing something is better than doing nothing and hoping someone else does it instead.

Comment: @Glorfindel - Thanks for the edit, but my choice of words was deliberate. "Duplicate" Means "More of the *same* flags" rather than "Additional"(potentially meaning "more, *different* flags")

Comment: @SiHa feel free to change it back - the reason why I changed it was because you can also flag a question as 'duplicate', so 'duplicate flags' is kind of ambiguous.

Comment: @Glorifndel. Ah, I hadn't considered that, thanks. I've reworded to clarify.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If it deserves a flag, go ahead and flag it.

> Is it clogging up a queue somewhere needlessly?

No.  Once it's in the close vote queue it stays there until reviewers close it, leave it open, or ignore it and the votes and [flags age away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204327/when-are-moderator-flags-automatically-dismissed-as-aged-away-by-the-system).  So there's not really any downside to correctly flagging something that *might* have been already flagged.  If a flag/close vote already exists, it will already be in the queue so no harm done.

> do additional flags actually help in some way?

They prevent the existing flags (for the same reason) and close votes from going stale and aging away.  This keeps the question in the review queue and possibly get it more attention.  Assuming you are flagging accurately, this prevents other existing close votes from aging away and being wasted.

Answer (score 18):

Off-topic flags don't accumulate - it might be that the question will appear earlier in the Close Votes review queue when there are multiple flags. For some additional information about that, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194515/sort-order-on-close-vote-queue). Regardless of the number of flags, it will still take 5 close votes from >3k-users to close the question.

Spam flags and rude/offensive flags *do* accumulate - when six people flag a post as such, it is automatically deleted.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the above answers, comment flags also accumulate. Multiple too chatty messages, for example, on a single comment will delete the comment.

Comment: Spam flags too.

Comment: @DavidG Yes, Glorfindel already said that.